# How to change background color for ui::TextField cocos 2dx (version 3.2)?

Tags: cocos2d-x, background-color

Im new to cocos and not able to set the background color of textField, the textField is black color by default and I want to change it to white.

Here is my code:

```
ui::TextField *textField = ui::TextField::create();
textField->setPosition(Vec2(visibleSize.width / 2.0f, visibleSize.height / 2.0f));
textField->setContentSize(Size(100 , 44));
textField->setPlaceHolder("Enter the words here");
textField->setFontSize(30);

this->addChild(textField);
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather  use ,
**//  CCTextFieldTTF Example**

we should have a white background sprite (their is no pre-built method for setting
background image).

CCTextFieldTTF *textfield = CCTextFieldTTF::textFieldWithPlaceHolder("ID를 입력해주세요.", 
    CCSize(480,30), kCCTextAlignmentCenter, "Arial", 20);

```
textfield->setAnchorPoint(CCPointZero);
textfield->setPosition(ccp(0,200));
textfield->setTag(100);
this->addChild(textfield);
```

attach with **CCIMEDelegate** to invoke the keyboard

**//  CCEditBox Example**

Here we can set the image while creating itself. (it is better than anything else)

CCEditBox *   m_pEditNameImport = CCEditBox::create(CCSize (VisibleRect::center().x/1.5421, VisibleRect::center().y/14.2222),CCScale9Sprite::createWithSpriteFrameName("text_field.png",CCRectZero),NULL,NULL);

m_pEditNameImport->setPosition(ccp(VisibleRect::center().x/0.9884,VisibleRect::center().y/1.7454));

```
//  m_pEditNameImport->setAnchorPoint(CCPointZero);
m_pEditNameImport->setFontColor(ccBLACK);
m_pEditNameImport->setMaxLength(15);
m_pEditNameImport->setInputMode(kEditBoxInputModeNumeric);
m_pEditNameImport->setReturnType(kKeyboardReturnTypeDone);
m_pEditNameImport->setInputFlag(kEditBoxInputFlagSensitive);
m_pEditNameImport->setPlaceHolder("");
m_pEditNameImport->cocos2d::CCLayerRGBA::setColor(ccWHITE);
m_pEditNameImport->setDelegate(this);
addChild(m_pEditNameImport,10);
m_pEditNameImport->retain();
```

use **cocos2d::extension::CCEditBoxDelegate**

Good luck